# What's the different betweet moment().utc().toISOString() and moment().utc().format()

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I'm using `moment` js library and I'm a bit confused by the result I'm getting about the timezone.

```
moment().utc().toISOString();
"2016-02-08T23:31:45.317Z"

moment().utc().format();
"2016-02-08T23:32:42+00:00"
```

What I don't understand is what is `317Z`? and What's the difference between `toISOString` and `format` And are they the same?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`"2016-02-08T23:31:45.317Z"` refer to the `CCYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SS.sss` time format.
`317` is the time in fractions of second while the Z means "Zulu time" (UTC).

Comment: which one is more common in application?

Comment: `format` uses the default format without milliseconds and maintains the timezone offset.

Comment: So it would be easier to understand without milliseconds.

Comment: Oh I'm so stupid. The 317 is the milliseconds and has nothing to do with timezone? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

In ISO 8601 there are multiple [time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Times) formats, e.g.

```
hh:mm:ss.sss
hh:mm:ss
```

And there are multiple ways to [specify the time zone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Time_zone_designators), e.g.

- `Z` means UTC time.
- `+00:00` means an offset of zero from UTC. So UTC too.